# How to convert all the characters in a file to ascii numbers in php

Tags: php, ascii

I want to covert all the characters in a file to ASCII code in php? I know of ord function but whether there is any function that will do for the entire file?

Comment: Only if you write it yourself... PHP provides built in functions for __almost__ everything, not for everything

Comment: I wrote this but it stops my server

set_time_limit(3000);
$file1=file_get_contents("v1.3gp");
$file2=str_split($file1);
foreach($file3 as $file2)
{
$file4=ord($file3);
$file5=$file5.$file4;

}
file_put_contents("a3.txt",$file5);

Answer (score 0):

iconv may do the work

http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php

it convertes chars of a specified charset in a string to another one. look at the //TRANSLIT and //IGNORE specials for chars that cannot be converted 1:1.

to get the file in a string you can use file_get_contents and save it after iconv etc. is applied with file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputFile = fopen("input.txt", "rb");
$outputFile = fopen("output.txt", "w+");

while (!feof($inputFile)) {
    $inputBlock = fread($inputFile, 8192);
    $outputBlock = '';
    $inputLength = strlen($inputBlock);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $inputLength; ++$i) {
        $outputBlock .= str_pad(dechex(ord($inputBlock{$i})),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    fwrite($outputFile,$outputBlock);
}

fclose($inputFile);
fclose($outputFile);
```